# Mysqlnd active connections number is too big. Is this normal?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlnd

I have `Windows 2003 Server`. `Apache 2.4.10, PHP 5.4.31 and MySQL 5.6.19` installed. There are two wordpress website running on server.

In the `phpinfo();` under `mysqlnd` section there says;

```
active_connections  18446744073709551563
```

is this number normal? If not how can I reduce it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old post, but this will help everyone else googling for this. (Much like me for hours today...)
https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/154232

It appears that -1 shows up as 18446744073709551613

Edit: This appears to be a PHP-related bug, per further investigation.